# Can i use HTML5 tags in a webpage with XHTML1.0 DOCTYPE

Tags: html, xhtml

**In short:** Can i use HTML5 tags in a XHTML1.0 page ?

Some of the websites,which i build are in `XHTML 1.0`,now i need to modify them and i am planning to add a few `HTML5` tags. Inorder to do that, is it necessary to change the doctype or will the `html5` tag works perfectly without changing the doctype? When i tried some `HTML5` tags in `XHTML 1.0` pages,its seems like working without any issues.so need some expert advice about the topic, whether i have to change the doctype or not and whats the need and benifit of changing the doctype?

Comment: AFAIK `<!doctype html>` is required for full support of HTML5 elements.

Comment: so adding, say the <header> tag, is it necessary to change the docktype?

Comment: Why don't you just change the doctype? The XHTML doctype is originally targeted at server side view technologies which use a XML tool/template to generate HTML (such as Facelets and ASP.NET). There was been a period wherein XHTML was extremely been overhyped and used "plain vanilla" by nitwits (i.e. without using any XML tool/template). Perhaps your page is such a leftover? Generally you can easily just turn it into `<!DOCTYPE html>` with perhaps some little CSS margin/padding fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document won't be valid (unless you limit yourself to those elements and attributes which also appear in XHTML 1.0) but that won't change how browsers handle them (browsers care about the Doctype only for switching between Quirks/Standards/Almost Standards modes).

Comment: so you are saying that, the document will be invalid, does this affect the rendering of the page? or what was the effect of this invalid document compared to the valid one.

Comment: In effects, only w3 validator will bark. But barking dogs don't bite. All modern browsers are lenient on this. Whether that's OK is a question you've to answer yourself.

Comment: @SobinAugustine — "does this affect the rendering of the page" — please read the second half of the answer. That **won't** change how browsers handle them.